# Sharepoint REST API (getting site app Document Library data)

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I'm new to the Sharepoint REST API and am a little lost trying to figure out how to access data. Currently my client has a SharePoint site setup with "Document Library" apps. Which I understand is nothing more than a database. There are custom columns/fields containing product data. For example:

Item Number, SKU, Product Name ,Product Price, etc...

I cant seem to figure out which endpoints to call to get information such as a field list (as the example able) as well as to get the actual data itself. I have been looking through the documentation and feel like I am looking in the wrong place.

My goal is to build a public facing catalog/site custom coded to integrate with the existing web site using JavaScript to access the API. End-users should be able to browse through a paginated list of products (which will be extracted from this data collection via the API).